# Dash to Dock and part of other gnome shell extensions can not load after I use compiz configure manager

Tags: linux, gnome, google-chrome-extensions, manjaro

This is the error log when I try to start dash to dock:

```
TypeError: ExtensionUtils.initTranslations is not a function

Stack trace:
  init@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/prefs.js:853:5
 _getExtensionPrefsModule@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:68:9
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  _selectExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:82:31
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  _onCommandLine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:235:17
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  main@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:389:5
  @<main>:1:43
```